# Auto indent html.erb in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have started using RubyMine but i have issue - in html.erb files auto indent doesn`t work. And even if I press reformat code it will be formatted in one column. How to solve this? I want that auto indent worked like in common html.

P.S. I`m using RubyMine 4.5.4

Comment: Can you provide a sample file to reproduce it? Does it happen with [5.0 EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP)?

Comment: I can`t reproduce it now, reboot helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting RubyMine solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the RubyMine does not recognize the file.html.erb as a "pure HTML file".

Try to rename (removing the .erb) just to see if it works.

Comment: It waorks if we rename the file.any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently RubyMine treats .erb file as .xml for formatting, hence just go to Options > Editor > Code Style > XML, and specify the number of indent columns will do

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can customize the formatting style of ERB by setting Options > Editor > Code Style > Other File Types.

It works for me.

[see in the jetbrains hub](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206703785-Indenting-ERB-templates-as-HTML?page=1)